# Invalid parameter in label /V - Format command

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I am using windows 10 OS. I am formatting pen drive using command prompt or batch file. I want to set volume label 'Local Backup'. But its showing error : *Invalid parameter - Backup'*

I know that NTFS support label upto 32 characters. I have tried :

```
format /FS:NTFS /Y /Q K: /V:'Local Backup'
format /FS:NTFS /Y /Q K: /V:"Local Backup"
format /FS:NTFS /Y /Q K: /V:[Local Backup]
```

[Format Command Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAGb3.png)

K: is USB Pen drive.

How set volume label (contains spaces) with format command ?

Comment: [This post from Superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/259421/how-to-include-space-in-drive-label-using-command-line-ms-format) might be helpful for you :)

Comment: As written in referenced answer on SuperUser where a question like this one should be asked because of being off-topic for Stack Overflow, the command `format` simply does not support labels with a space inside. It is only possible to use for example `/V:LocalBackup`. That's it. The workaround solution was also posted on SuperUser. This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow as it is not about programming, just about how to use console application `format`. That this command is used in a batch file does not make this question a programming related question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use label as :

```
format /FS:NTFS /Y /Q K:
label K: Local Backup
```

or if you are using it in C#.net then use can use class DriveInfo as :

```
DriveInfo.VolumeLabel("Local Backup");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "Double Quotes" Single quotes won't cut it.

It appears that the limit is 11 characters. I found that "some name" worked using this format.

```
format d: /q /x 0<"labeller.txt"
```

also worked for me, where `labeller.txt` is a text file (duh) with the first line blank and the second line containing the required label.

However, it appears to have kittens if the attempted label is longer than 11 characters or no doubt if it contains invalid characters (this last not tested but inferred)